# Method of Frobenius Confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation, recurrence-relations, frobenius-method, multivariate-polynomial

$x^2 y'' + 3xy' + (1 - 2x)y = 0$

I plugged in the guess $y = x^s \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n$ to get $(s^2 + 2s + 1)a_0 x^s + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n^2 + 2ns + s^2 + 2n + 2s + 1)a_n x^{n + s} - 2a_{n - 1}x^{n + s} = 0$.

The indicial equation indicates that $s = -1$ with Algebraic Multiplicity $2$, and the summation leads to the recurrence relation $a_n = \frac{2}{n^2 + 2ns + s^2 + 2n + 2s + 1} a_{n - 1}$.  My understanding is that now I am supposed to solve this recurrence relation and take the partial derivative of the solution with respect to $s$ evaluated (after partial differentiation) at $s = -1$.

So far, I haven't been able to find any really *good* techniques to solve the recurrence relations produced by power series ODE solution methods; I either write out some terms of the recurrence relation and pray that the pattern doesn't take half an hour to spot, or Wolfram the answer to the recurrence relation.  Characteristic equations, generating functions, and $Z$-Transforms have been unhelpful due to the variable coefficients, and although intuition from analogy to ODEs tells me that first-order linear recurrences should be solvable even with variable coefficients, I have yet to find a reliable technique.

Often the pattern matching flash of insight doesn't come to me or takes an extreme amount of trial and error, and now that $s$'s have been introduced into the recurrence relations, the pattern matching approach has become even less productive.  Unfortunately, [Wolfram's answer to the recurrence relation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a_n%20%3D%202a_%28n%20-%201%29%2F%28n%5E2%20%2B%202n%20*%20s%20%2B%20s%5E2%20%2B%202n%20%2B%202s%20%2B%201%29%2C%20a_0%20%3D%20pi) ($a_0$ set to $\pi$ to prevent lumping) involves Gamma functions, which cannot be differentiated nicely (with or without logarithmic differentiation).  I am unsure if the Gamma functions are allowed to be converted into factorials, since in this problem, $s = -1$ and therefore $s + 2$ and $n + s + 2$ are positive integers, but it certainly wouldn't be allowed in problems where $s$ was not an integer.

My suspicion is that Wolfram is treating $s$ as a constant, but I need it to be treating both $n$ and $s$ as variables when solving the recurrence relation, since the plan is to partially differentiate with respect to $s$, and partially differentiating with respect to a constant won't work.  However, Wolfram doesn't seem to do multivariable recurrence relations, and I have been once again unable to find techniques.

Am I understanding the prescription of Forbenius solution method correctly, or am I on the wrong track?  How can I proceed with recurrence relations like this when the solution isn't obvious from writing out terms?

Comment: We solve the recurrence relation $c_k = f(k - 1) c_{k - 1}$ (with a parameter $s$). Then we differentiate wrt $s$ by using the product rule:
$$c_k = \frac {2 c_{k - 1}} {(k + s + 1)^2} =
2^k c_0 \prod_{0 \leq i < k} \frac 1 {(i + s + 2)^2}, \\
c_k' = \left. \frac \partial {\partial s} c_k \right|_{s = -1} =
-\frac {2^{k + 1} c_0} {(k!)^2} \sum_{0 \leq i < k} \frac 1 {i + 1}, \\
y_2 = \left. \frac \partial {\partial s}
 \sum_{k \geq 0} c_k x^{k + s} \right|_{s = -1} =
c_0 \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac {2^k} {(k!)^2} x^{k - 1} \ln x +
\sum_{k \geq 0} c_k' x^{k - 1}.$$

Comment: @Maxim I have a couple of confused questions about this.  First of all, does the choice to leave the recurrence relation solution in $\Pi$ notation rather than finding the final solution generally reduce the solution process to applying a fixed set of rules, rather than trying to find the right insight?  Secondly, if $s$ is a parameter and not a variable, why isn't the partial derivative with respect to it undefined?  If we do treat $s$ as a variable in order to take the partial derivative, why aren't we obligated to redo the recurrence relation where we treat $s$ as a second variable?

Comment: Sure there are more complicated cases: to begin with, there can be more than two terms in the recurrence relation. In this case, we can find a closed form for the product and then differentiate the closed form, but gamma and polygamma functions won't really make the form of the solution more transparent. Parameter and variable are just words we use for convenience. This is just how the method works; to get some insight into why it works, see, for instance, Bender, Orszag, *Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers*.